# Can i store a pointer to forward declared classes/structs?

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct B;
struct A {
    B* b;
    int num = 4;
    
    A() {
        b = new B(this);
    }
};

struct A;
struct B {
    A* a;
    int num = 21;
    
    B(A* a) {
        this->a = a;
    }
    
    // function that does stuff with both A and B nums
    int add() {
        return num + a->num;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A thing;
    printf("%d",thing.b->add());
    return 0;
}
```

So I have two structs in my code, where struct `B` is a member of struct `A`. I just want them to store pointers to each other so that they can access each other's member variables. Is this even possible? I'm open to refactor suggestions.

Comment: Yes that's possible. To dereference the pointer, the full class definition needs to be visible at that point though.

Comment: The first question is going to be "Why?" as this is an unusual thing to do and complicates memory management significantly.

Comment: Presumably your code is giving an error? Are `A` and `B` declared in different files? Moving the definitions of your functions out of line is probably the way to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible but you're going to have to move some code around because many expressions cannot be compiled until the type is fully known. For instance `new B(this)` cannot be compiled until `B` is fully known.

So the `A` constructor needs to be compiled after `B` is defined, like this

```
struct B;

struct A {
    B* b;
    int num = 4;
    
    A();
};

struct B {
    A* a;
    int num = 21;
    
    B(A* a) {
        this->a = a;
    }
    
    // function that does stuff with both A and B nums
    int add() {
        return num + a->num;
    }
};

inline A::A() {
    b = new B(this);
}

int main()
{
    A thing;
    printf("%d",thing.b->add());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! I didn't know `inline` could be used to control what the compiler sees.

Comment: @ankien It's the order of the definitions that is controlling what the compiler sees. The code would compile perfectly well without `inline`. I just put it there because `A::A()` was inline in your original code because it was inside the class. Now it's outside the class you have to add `inline` if that is what you want it to be.

Comment: @ankien it doesn't control what the compiler sees, its just a hint to the linker that it is OK to have multiple copies of a function, its required when defining functions outside of a class in a header file